# How to explain why categorical inputs (as is) versus categorical inputs (as binary) produce different coefficients in logistic regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

**Background**

When using logistic regression, I observe that using categorical inputs (as-is i.e. leaving them as categorical with type factor) versus using said categorical inputs but transforming them into binaries (i.e. dummy variables) produce different coefficients.

**Question**

1. How do I explain why the two above-mentioned methods produce different coefficients, hence different interpretations of the model's inputs?
2. When do I use one versus the other?

**Example (coded in R)**

Here is an example using the *titanic* dataset (not the best example but I hope you get the point).

Dataset came from:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?select=train.csv

```
# This dataset has been saved to my desktop. I now import this dataset
setwd("C:/Users/kimye/Dropbox/Project - Data Science/Ad-Hoc/Logistic Regression - Compare categorical and binary input")
dat <- read.csv('titanic - train set.csv')

# Load library
library(tidyverse)

# select variables for modelling
dat1 <- select(dat, PassengerId, Survived, Sex, Age, Embarked)

# Impute NA
dat1$Age[is.na(dat1$Age)] <- mean(dat1$Age, na.rm = T)

# Change target to factor
dat1$Survived <- as.factor(dat1$Survived)

# Fit logistic regression
log_regr_1 <- glm(Survived ~ . , 
                data=dat1,
                family = binomial(link = 'logit')
               )

# View output                
summary(log_regr_1)
```

This is the model's output.

```
Call:
glm(formula = Survived ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = dat1)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0747  -0.6214  -0.5745   0.8187   2.0504  

Coefficients:
               Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  13.8538826 378.5896017   0.037    0.971    
PassengerId   0.0002150   0.0003242   0.663    0.507    
Sexmale      -2.5162654   0.1720593 -14.624   <2e-16 ***
Age          -0.0076739   0.0065830  -1.166    0.244    
EmbarkedC   -11.9395966 378.5895203  -0.032    0.975    
EmbarkedQ   -13.0054759 378.5895703  -0.034    0.973    
EmbarkedS   -12.8310676 378.5894881  -0.034    0.973    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1186.66  on 890  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  895.58  on 884  degrees of freedom
AIC: 909.58

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 12
```

Now, I try a different version where I transform the categorical variables to binaries (dummy variables).

```
# assign to a new dataset
dat2 <- dat1

### sex ###

dat2_sex <- dat2 %>% select(PassengerId, Sex)
dat2_sex$sex_flag <- rep(1, nrow(dat2_sex))
dat2_sex <- dat2_sex %>% spread(Sex, sex_flag)
dat2_sex$female[is.na(dat2_sex$female)] <- 0
dat2_sex$male[is.na(dat2_sex$male)] <- 0

### Embarked ###

dat2_embarked <- dat2 %>% select(PassengerId, Embarked)
dat2_embarked$embarked_flag <- rep(1, nrow(dat2_embarked))
dat2_embarked <- dat2_embarked %>% spread(Embarked, embarked_flag)
dat2_embarked$V1[is.na(dat2_embarked$V1)] <- 0
dat2_embarked$C[is.na(dat2_embarked$C)] <- 0
dat2_embarked$Q[is.na(dat2_embarked$Q)] <- 0
dat2_embarked$S[is.na(dat2_embarked$S)] <- 0

### join to main dataset ###

dat2 <- dat2 %>%
     select(-Sex, -Embarked) %>%
     left_join(dat2_sex, by = 'PassengerId') %>%
     left_join(dat2_embarked, by = 'PassengerId')


# Fit logistic regression
log_regr_2 <- glm(Survived ~ . , 
                  data=dat2,
                  family = binomial(link = 'logit')
)

# View output                
summary(log_regr_2)
```

Here is the model's output.

```
Call:
glm(formula = Survived ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = dat2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0747  -0.6214  -0.5745   0.8187   2.0504  

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
               Estimate  Std. Error z value     Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.4934505   0.2701625  -5.528 0.0000000324 ***
PassengerId   0.0002150   0.0003242   0.663        0.507    
Age          -0.0076739   0.0065830  -1.166        0.244    
female        2.5162654   0.1720593  14.624      < 2e-16 ***
male                 NA          NA      NA           NA    
V1           12.8310676 378.5894881   0.034        0.973    
C             0.8914710   0.2098452   4.248 0.0000215465 ***
Q            -0.1744083   0.2974947  -0.586        0.558    
S                    NA          NA      NA           NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1186.66  on 890  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  895.58  on 884  degrees of freedom
AIC: 909.58

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 12
```

Comment: roughly speaking you are doing the same thing within your code... with factors glm explicitly creates a set of vartiables that are linearly independent, and by creating binaries and then passing to glm it does it in a slighly different way (see2 not defined because of singularities)) so it estimates a male and intercept represents female "base" effect (so sign is opposite)

Comment: If `sex` has two levels you only need one dummy variable to express `sex`. The second dummy has no additional information so warrants no coefficient of its own. @seanv507 that is a great answer. If you make it an answer, people will know that there is an answer, people can upvote it und KYG can accept it.

Comment: I believe you would benefit from studying the topic of *contrasts* (in particular treatment contrasts, which R constructs by default).

Comment: @seanv507 what about variable 'Embark C' ? As factor, it has a negative coefficient and was not statistically significant. But as binary, it has a positive coefficient and was highly statistically significant.

Comment: @KYG its the same issue just as you have to choose whether to have a male coef or a female coefficient because the two are redundant, so are V1,C,Q,S embarcation types.  Embark C coefficient means deviation from base embarcation (in one case its deviation from V1, in the other its deviation from S).  Its got nothing to do with dummy coding, but which you drop - which i sbeing done automatically for you in two different ways

Comment: @seanv507 Thanks, your explanation helps.